# Laravel 5.1 - Check if a visitor has already visited a profile (unix timestamp)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table with the following columns.

> - id *(profile id)*                        **int(10)**
> - viewer *(visitor id)*                    **int(10)**
> - ip *(visitor ip)*                        **int(10)**
> - ts *(unix timestamp)*                    **int(10)**

Now, I want to query if the visitor x, has visited profile y today.

My thought is that, I want to do something like this.

```
public function hasVisitToday(Profile $profile)
{
    $dt = Carbon::now();

    if(ViewTrack::where('id', $profile)->where('viewer', $visitor)->whereDate('ts', $dt->today())->first())
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

The project use Laravel 5.1, and one of the main problems is, that the database store the timestamp as „unix timestamp“ in a int column and not as timestamp column.

And I'm searching for the best way to handle this.

Comment: Its time to change  the structure it should be `timestamp` instead

Comment: That s true, but this is not in my decision.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ViewTrack::where('id', $profile)
    ->where('viewer', $visitor)
    ->where('ts', '>=', $dt->startOfDay()->timestamp())
    ->count())
```

You should be able to compare Unix timestamps if they're both in the same format.

I tend towards agreeing with the above comment that I'd rather have it in a human readable format so that I can see if I'm getting any weird dates.

If you get any funny business make sure your server, MySQL server and laravel config timezones all match.

Comment: Don't know who downvoted -- OP did you get to try this code?

Answer (score 0):

Thank's Zoe, 
but i choose the whereBetween statement and this is my solution.

```
        $carbon = Carbon::now();
        $start  = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();

        $visit = ViewTrack::where('id', $this->id)
            ->where('viewer', $visitor->id)
            ->whereBetween('ts', [$start->timestamp , $carbon->timestamp])
            ->get();

        if($visit->count() > 0)
            return true;

        return false;
```

Comment: Should work! Is there a reason you're checking if they visited this profile after right now?

Comment: And you can use count instead of get() to get the count without fetching the resource collection along the way :)